# using gorm case expression with gorm smart select fields

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

i have a query to a table with joins.  i will store the result of the query in the following variable.

```
var listItems itemModel
```

my itemModel is a joined table. the joined table will be like this

```
ID uint
table1ID uint
table1Item table1Model `json:",omitempty" gorm:"foreignKey:table1ID; References:ID;->"`
table2ID uint
table2Item table2Model  `json:",omitempty" gorm:"foreignKey:table2ID; References:ID;->"`
```

i am using gorm joins method for joining table1Item and table2Item and  uses gorm smart select fields for selecting each columns(my itemModel contains column name i want to display). problem is that when i try to use postgres case expression in my query , i loose all control of my query. because case expression have to be called inside select () method of gorm. which cause me loose all the convenient method offered by gorm for joining tables and smart selecting the fields

i saw some documentation in github to use case expression inside select statement and in some article to use raw sql query